# Graphics confusion

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I am compiling a latex file like this:

```
pdflatex path/to/file.tex
```

There is a png in the same directory as the `.tex` file: `path/to/img.png`

I get an error, presumably because pdflatex is looking in the directory from which I am calling `pdflatex`.  I can't put the directory of the `.tex` file and the png in my `\graphicspath` statement because the directory is being dynamically generated with an md5 hash - i.e., I don't know it ahead of time.

Is there any other way to tell pdflatex to look in the same directory as the `.tex` file?

Comment: I think you want the command `\graphicspath`.  Try `texdoc grfguide` to get the docs (assuming TeX Live).

Comment: I had an error in my original post. Please see edit.

Comment: cd path/to/   ; pdflatex file.tex

Comment: is there any other way if I want to stay in that top directory?  This is part of a bigger application, the details of which I left out for sanity/clarity here.  I have "reasons" for wanting to execute pdflatex from that higher directory.  Can I pass an argument when I call `pdflatex` or something?

Comment: export TEXINPUTS=path/to: ; pdflatex file  would also work. (or setenv or set or whatever you need to set an environment variable)

Comment: Thank you!  Is there anything horribly inefficient about doing that every time I compile a document?

Answer (score 2):

graphics are searched on the standard TEXINPUTS path so rather than

```
pdflatex path/to/file
```

You can do

```
export TEXINPUTS=path/to: ; pdflatex file
```

(or `setenv` or `set` or whatever you need to set an environment variable)